# Excel VLOOKUP true or false issue

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vlookup, xlookup, textbefore

I have some names from g6 to g9 on "Sheet 1" of my excel:

- Z Purton
- H Bowman
- C L Chau(-2)
- M F Poon(-7)

I have these names in column B of another sheet called "Names" but in a different order, and also without the "(-2)":

- M F Poon
- H Bowman
- Z Purton
- C L Chau

In column L of the same sheet, I have a bunch of numbers which are the points corresponding to the names.

Back to sheet1 of my excel, i did

```
=VLOOKUP(I6, Names!$B$5:$L$55, 11, FALSE)
```

This worked for the first two names, printing their scores, 0.75 and 0.5, but then it said #N/A for the last two names as they had a number next to them, making them not match the names from Sheet 1.

I then tried to do

```
=VLOOKUP(I6, TrainerRanking!$B$5:$L$55, 11, TRUE)
```

Now, there were no more #N/A's. However, for the first name - Z Purton, it should have printed 0.75 but it printed 0

is there a way to fix this?

Comment: Use `TEXTBEFORE()` function --> `=VLOOKUP(TEXTBEFORE(I6,"(",,,1,I6), Names!$B$5:$L$55, 11, FALSE)`

Comment: Or use `XLOOKUP()` and `TEXTBEFORE()` --> `=XLOOKUP(TEXTBEFORE(I6:I9,"(",,,1,I6:I9), Names!B5:B55, Names!L5:L55, "")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using <kbd>TEXTBEFORE( )</kbd>

```
=VLOOKUP(TEXTBEFORE(I6,"(",,,1,I6), Names!$B$5:$L$55, 11, FALSE)
```

---

Or,

```
=XLOOKUP(TEXTBEFORE(I6:I9,"(",,,1,I6:I9), Names!B5:B55, Names!L5:L55, "")
```

---

The <kbd>TEXTBEFORE( )</kbd> function has `2` mandatory parameters and `4` optional parameters, the parameters which shows within square brackets are called optional.

So that said, the <kbd>TEXTBEFORE( )</kbd> Function syntax is

```
=TEXTBEFORE(text,delimiter,[instance_num],[match_mode],[match_end],[if_not_found])
```

therefore in the above formula I have used the function as

```
=TEXTBEFORE(I6:I9,"(",,,1,I6:I9)
```

hope you can relate it now. Where `I6:I9` is my **text**, `(` is my **delimiter**, **instance_num** and **match_mode** is nothing here taken, while the **match_end** is `1` & if not found is same `I6:I9`.

You can also read the MS Documentation **[here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/textbefore-function-d099c28a-dba8-448e-ac6c-f086d0fa1b29)**

---

Alternative approach for all users, as mentioned in comments by **[P.b](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12634230/p-b)** Sir.

```
=VLOOKUP(IFERROR(LEFT(I6,FIND("(",I6)-1),I6),Names!$B$5:$L$55,11,0)
```

---

Comment: Thanks, just wondering, what does ",,,1" do? I'm a bit confused on why there are three commas next to each other

Comment: @NNBananas yeah sure let me tell you, the `1` means `[match_end]` which is an optional parameter.

Comment: @NNBananas the `TEXTBEFORE()` function has `2` mandatory parameters and `4` optional parameters, the parameters which shows within square brackets are called optional. So that said, the `TEXTBEFORE()` Function syntax is `=TEXTBEFORE(text,delimiter,[instance_num],[match_mode],[match_end],[if_not_found])` therefore in the above formula i have used the function as `=TEXTBEFORE(I6:I9,"(",,,1,I6:I9)` hope you can relate it now. Where `I6:I9` is my **text**, `(` is my **delimiter**, **instance_num** and **match_mode** is nothing here taken, while the **match_end** is `1` & if not found is same I6:I9

Comment: @NNBananas glad to know that, you can also read the same thing here with some examples given by **Microsoft** **[here read](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/textbefore-function-d099c28a-dba8-448e-ac6c-f086d0fa1b29)**

Comment: @MayukhBhattacharya you should put that explanation into your answer, as comments may not survive.

Comment: For older Excel versions one could use `=VLOOKUP(IFERROR(LEFT(I6,FIND("(",I6)-1),I6),Names!$B$5:$L$55,11,0)`

Answer (score 1):

Here is another way:

[image]

```
INDEX($B$10:$B$13,MATCH(IFERROR(LEFT(A3,FIND("(",A3,1)-1),A3),$A$10:$A$13,0))
```

Adding trim() may be useful as the "(-2) etc may pick up a space prior, so:

```
INDEX($B$10:$B$13,MATCH(TRIM(IFERROR(LEFT(A3,FIND("(",A3,1)-1)),A3),$A$10:$A$13,0))
```

Also, this will work in earlier versions of Excel prior to those useful functions like textbefore() and textafter()...